# How to split an array into single quotes and comma separated list in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

for instance if i have an array in javascript

```
var productIds = ["abc", "xyz", "123"]; //having string elements
```

my desired output is not only to comma separate the array but surround each element with quotes.

```
'abc', 'xyz', '123'
```

I can do up to join, `productIds.join(', ')` but how to surround with quotes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add the quotes into the `join` and then wrap the resulting string in quotes as well. No need to add any extra overhead when it can be done more efficiently and be more readable.

```
"'" + myArray.join("', '") + "'";
```

The only case where this fails is with an empty array, so you can just test length in that case (the brackets aren't necessary, they're just for readability again):

```
myArray.length ? ( "'" + myArray.join("', '") + "'" ) : '';
```

Comment: The `map` covers empty arrays a little more cleanly, both are viable and about even really

Answer (score 7):

You can use `.map()`:

```
var quotedIds = productIds.map(function(id) { return "'" + id + "'"; }).join(", ");
```

The `.map()` function is available in newer browsers; if you need your code to work in an older browser, you can either include a shim or else simply implement that as a simple loop:

```
var quotedIds = [];
for (var i = 0; i < productIds.length; ++i)
  quotedIds.push("'" + productIds[i] + "'");
quotedIds = quotedIds.join(", ");
```

Comment: good solution, but can be a lot more compact nowadays with ES6 syntax: `let quotedIds = productIds.map(id => \`'${id}'\`).join(", ");`